# Proper way to record custom New Relic attribute across entire Rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, newrelic

I'm using New Relic to monitor my Rails 4.2 app, and it works well.

However, I want to be able to know which user encountered an error when New Relic reports one to me.

I've read [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/using-new-relic-custom-metrics-to-monitor-all-the-things--net-36260), which I believe explains how to add a custom attribute on a *per-controller* basis.

However, in my case, I want to record `current_user.id` as a custom attribute across the *entire* app.

My first thought was to put the following into `applications_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  ::NewRelic::Agent.add_custom_parameters(
    :user_name => current_user.full_name rescue "Not a logged-in user.",
    :user_id => current_user.id rescue "Not a logged-in user."
  )
```

... but that caused a server error.

Any suggestions?

**Update/Solution**

There were two issues with what I was doing above. First, I was using `rescue` improperly. Second, I needed to create a method for adding these custom attributes **and** call that method in `ApplicationController` before everything by using `before_filter`. Here is a sample of what ended up working for me:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  # attempt to gather user and organization attributes before all controller actions for New Relic error logging
  before_filter :record_new_relic_custom_attributes

  def record_new_relic_custom_attributes
    # record some custom attributes for New Relic
    new_relic_user_id = current_user.id rescue "Not a logged-in user."
    new_relic_user_name = current_user.full_name rescue "Not a logged-in user."
    new_relic_user_email = current_user.email rescue "Not a logged-in user."
    new_relic_organization_id = current_organization.id rescue "Not a logged-in user."
    new_relic_organization_name = current_organization.name rescue "Not a logged-in user."
    new_relic_organization_email = current_organization.email rescue "Not a logged-in user."
    ::NewRelic::Agent.add_custom_parameters(
      :user_id => new_relic_user_id,
      :user_name => new_relic_user_name,
      :user_email => new_relic_user_email,
      :organization_id => new_relic_organization_id,
      :organization_name => new_relic_organization_name,
      :organization_email => new_relic_organization_email
    )
  end
```

**Update 2**
As per one of the commenters below, using `rescue` isn't ideal in this case, instead I should have used `try`:

```
new_relic_user_id = current_user.try(:id) || "Not a logged-in user."
```

Comment: Could you please post details as to what the "server error" was?

Comment: in my case, the error was due to the improper use of rescue in my first example above.

Comment: I know this is a rather old question but as a rule of thumb always be careful of outputting Personal Identifiable information (PII) in logs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to include that code in a filter so that it runs before your controller actions, for example:

```ruby
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_new_relic_user
                                                    
  def set_new_relic_user
    ::NewRelic::Agent.add_custom_parameters(
      user_name: current_user&.full_name || "Not a logged-in user.",
      user_id: current_user&.id || "Not a logged-in user."
    )                                                
  end
end
```

Comment: I would also remove the inline `rescue`, because it's quite an expensive operation, and it is used twice in this method, which will be executed on each request.

Comment: Even `current_user.try(:full_name) || "Not a logged-in user."` would be better here

Comment: @YuryLebedev wrong motivation. Right motivation is: developer mistake like `fllu_nmae` will be rescued as well.